# Drag and Drop Folders no working in Chrome browser for Chromebook

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, drag-and-drop, google-chrome-os, chromebook

Setup:
Chrome Browser Version 65.0.3325.9 (Official Build) dev (32-bit) on  Acer Chromebook

I am trying to support drag and drop of folders for my app from within Chrome browser. 
I use DataTransferItem API listed here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransferItem.

For files I get a list. However, for folders the drop event does not return any file information. I also confirmed the behavior using https://mdn.mozillademos.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransferItem/webkitGetAsEntry$samples/Example?revision=1125119

Can someone confirm if drag and drop for folders does not work on Chrome for ChromeOS? It works fine on Windows and Linux OS.

Thanks.

Comment: i can only say for me: it has been broken since i bought it, about 5 months ago.

Comment: I have same issue. Any solution?